# Negative BIC values for GaussianMixture in scikit-learn (sklearn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, probability, bayesian

In `scikit-learn`, the `GaussianMixture` object has the method `bic(X)` that implements the Bayesian Information Criterion to choose the number of components that better fits the data.
This is an example of usage:

```
from sklearn import mixture
for n in range(0,10):
    gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=n, max_iter=1000, covariance_type='diag', n_init=50)
    gmm.fit(data)
    bic_n = gmm.bic(data)
```

I am fitting a GMM on a dataset with 600k rows and 7 columns. The BIC values are always negative, e.g. `[-2000, -3000, -3300, ..]`. 
In the documentation of the method `bic()`, it says "The lower the better". In the case of negative values as in my example, is then `-3300` the best value, or it refers to the lowest value in absolute terms?

Answer (score 2):

**Generally, the aim is to minimize BIC, so if you are in negative territory, a negative number that has the largest modulus (deepest down in the negative territory) indicates the preferred model.**

Look at the source code: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/mixture/_gaussian_mixture.py#L727

```
    def bic(self, X):
        """Bayesian information criterion for the current model on the input X.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array of shape (n_samples, n_dimensions)
        Returns
        -------
        bic : float
            The lower the better.
        """
        return (-2 * self.score(X) * X.shape[0] +
                self._n_parameters() * np.log(X.shape[0]))
```